# Do electricity bills include surge power, energy, or both?

Tags: motor, surge

I read that motor-driven appliances have additional surge power, which makes it better to turn it on for some times rather than on and off in short period of time.

Is it because the electric bills are calculated by including the surge power + energy, or will the surge power not be calculated?

Comment: I think you need to link the full script of what you read.

Comment: Your electricity meter measures energy consumed, not peak power. Since energy = power x time and time is very short for a surge or inrush, this is nothing you need to worry about.

Comment: You need to know if you are on a residential bill or a commercial bill - commercial bills include power factor charges, and are often tiered above certain kWh rates.

Comment: Residential tariffs do not charge extra for surge power, just the amount of energy (pls fixed fees). Commercial tariffs may include extra charges for surges or power factor.

Comment: @KevinWhite: I know some relatives whose residential electric bill includes a demand charge for peak consumption.

Comment: @BenVoigt - unusual - where is that?

Comment: @KevinWhite in Florida north of St Pete, can't remember the nearby town off-hand

Answer (score 3):

Electricity bills can, in theory, be charged however the provider and consumer agree on.  In the US (and, I think, most other places) you get charged for the line hookup (or some minimum kilowatt-hour) and then per kilowatt-hour on top of that.

Note that the name "kilowatt-hour" can be a bit misleading.  What your meter is actually measuring is not "watts".  It is measuring the accrued energy that you are consuming*.

Motors tend to take a surge current when they're starting, with that energy partially being wasted as heat and partially being invested in the kinetic energy of rotation of the motor.  Then they have a more-or-less steady state operation.

As to motors starting and stopping -- there are a whole lot of factors that go into whether a machine is efficient, and even more that go into whether it is working "well".  One of those efficiency factors is how often the motor(s) start and stop -- but it's not the only one.  One of the factors in motor wear is also whether it's starting or stopping a lot -- but sometimes you just *need* the motor to be starting and stopping all the time.

If you are *building* a machine, and you can only turn the motors entirely on or entirely off, then it's a good thing to design the rest of the machine so that happens less often.  But there's a sensible limit to everything, so you'd need to look at all the factors, not just of efficiency, but of "working well" (whatever that means *for you*) to make that decision.

For that matter, if you're building a machine, then its also often more efficient to soft-start motors and to make them run at less than full speed, with the motor speed trimmed to the job at hand.  40 years ago this was only done in the biggest factory machines, and would have been considered absurdly expensive for household appliances -- today, just about big household appliance has variable speed motors in it, for the reasons cited above**.

* Ignore this bit if you find it confusing -- the meter is *integrating*  (accruing) watts over time.  So 1kW for one hour integrates to 1kW-H, but so does 10kW for six minutes, or 100W for 10 hours.

** Except, apparently, durability -- but that's not the fault of the motor control per se.

Answer (score 1):

Wattage is **power**. The units are watts.

Bills are for **energy** consumed in a specified period such as a month.

Energy is power x time.

The units of energy are kiloWatt-hours (kWh). Science and engineering use SI units of energy, which are Joules. But electricity suppliers bill you in kWh as a matter of tradition and alleged convenience.

Therefore, assuming your meter is accurate, your bills correctly reflect energy consumed at surge wattage, energy consumed at normal running wattage and energy consumed when the motor is idle (probably negligible).

This answer ignores power factors (VA vs Watts). You probably should too, unless you are an industrial consumer of electrical power.

Answer (score 1):

There are two power billing charges in the U.S. and probably other countries.

There is the normal usage charges that others have answered.

For **commercial & industrial** users, there is an additional charge called **Peak Demand Charge** (PDC), also called Facilities-Related Demand, which is the largest power consumption in a, usually, 15 minute period for the billing period multiplied by a rate. In the area I live, the PDC rate is about USD 6.75 per kW.

Example, if the business has a peak demand of 50kW in a 15 minute period only once per month, there will be an additional charge of 50 x 6.75 = USD 337.50. The PDC can be a significant portion of the power bill.

Comment: And this has become an interesting issue with electric vehicle charging stations and where they are sited, since they have high peak demands.